# associating a model with a route in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, javascript-framework, ember-model

As I understad, a template in emberjs gets it's data from controller. So, it's a controller's job to get hold of `model` data and present it to the template.

The docs [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/) associate a model with a route like this:

```
App.FavoritesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // the model is an Array of all of the posts
    return App.Post.find();
  }
});
```

In this case and `ArrayController` is automatically generated.

However, there's also the `setupController` function. So, can we also do this :

```
App.FavoritesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('model', App.Post.find());
  }
});
```

as the first example given [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/) do?

Do the two ways do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

> Do the two ways do the same thing?

Almost. In both cases the controller's `content` property will be set to the result of `App.Post.find()`. And both will *work*.

That said, using the model hook is the preferred way to do this. If your model hook returns a promise, the router will wait for it to resolve before moving on. That is not the case with the setupController hook. generally you will want to avoid anything async from the `setupController` hook.